# adjust width on c++ program

Tags: c++, size, width

How can i adjust width on the window of a c++ program so when the user runs the program,it will automatically be at the desirable width.

Thanks

Comment: your question lacks a lot of details. Operating System? GUI library?

Comment: You need to add lot more details. Which platform you are using? which library you are using for GUI development etc. C++ as such doesn't have any concept of windows.

Comment: Window handling is not part of the C++ standard, so you'll have to give some more info on libraries/toolkit you are using.

Comment: It depends on what GUI you are using. Is it a windows application? Linux/Unix? Mac? etc. And there are also different frameworks for each system - Mac uses Cocoa, Windows MFC, GTK, QT etc. So be more specific to get the right answer ;-)

Comment: i use windows.i have made the application but i cant adjust the width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This adjusts the console on windows.

```
COORD s = { 120, 2000 };
SMALL_RECT sr = { 0, 0, 119, 49 };
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sbi = { 0 };
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &sbi);
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), s);
if ( (sbi.srWindow.Right - sbi.srWindow.Left) != (sr.Right - sr.Left) ) {
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), TRUE, &sr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is for the Win32 platform and uses a call to `CreateWindow`, this can be adjusted by modifying the sixth parameter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It is a console application.I don't user createwindow

Answer (score 0):

Your question raises more questions, but if you can answer the following, you may be a few steps nearer to getting where you want to be:

1. What windowing system are you using? In conjunction with which C++ compiler?
2. What do you define as 'desireable width?' Desireable for whom?

Now, with you answers to these questions, you should be able to search the web and come up with reference material and examples inside of about 10 minutes. Then try plugging into your design the answer from question two.

When you've done all this and it still doesn't work, come back here with more details and some real code.

Comment: @akageek: then post the code that's causing the errors and post the errors too.

Comment: Erik helped me with his answer.I don't have time to prove you what i have done until now.

Comment: i don't have 15 reputation to vote it up.I found the solution.Don't be so negative.